# Update record into current json array angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to update new row data in my current Address Array but its not updating,
See below images, I am new in Angular, add other object of array see last image

```
<tbody class="gradeX">
                <tr  ng-repeat="x in Profile.addresses">
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.site_name ' name='site_name'></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.street_address ' name='street_address'></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.city ' name='city'></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.state ' name='state'></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.country ' name='country'></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.zip_code ' name='zip_code'></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.phone_number ' name='phone_number'></td>

                <tr ng-repeat="lines in array">
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.site_name ' name='site_name'></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.street_address ' name='street_address'></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.city ' name='city'></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.state ' name='state'></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.country ' name='country'></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.zip_code ' name='zip_code'></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.phone_number ' name='phone_number'></td>

                                            </tr>
                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody>
<a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Address" ng-click="addRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x cust_primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Code Snippet for Adding new row in Address Array:

```
      $scope.i = 0;
    $scope.array = [];
       $scope.addRow = function() {
        $scope.i++;
        $scope.array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.i; i++) {
            $scope.array.push(i);
        }
    }
```

Code Snippet for Updating Textbox values into database:

```
      $scope.updateProfile = function () {       

            $scope.tempObject={full_name:$scope.Profile.full_name,
              mobile_number:$scope.Profile.mobile_number,
             company_name:$scope.Profile.company_name,
             designation: $scope.Profile.designation,    
            addresses: $scope.Profile.addresses,
            payment_info: $scope.Profile.payment_info

           };  

   addresses: $scope.Profile.addresses,
```

In Below Picture I click button (+) to generate new row with empty textfields:
[image]

After row appears, I enter some data:
[image]

When i Click Update button  yellow highlighted new row data does not save, it shows old records after i refresh my page

[image]

My question in Simple. How to update the Address array with new row ?
[image]

Comment: I do not see where you are sending the new information to any database.  Do you have a service to send to the database?  Or are you just trying to update the array on the screen?

Comment: profile.address array i want new row data also add

Comment: 2 rows i was added back-end but 3 row i add from front but its not add  address array

Comment: From where are you getting the data for Profile.address.......from db or just a hard-coded JSON

Comment: when i enter ng-model=' Profile.addresses[2].site_name like this working fine but how to get array index ? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you just need to push the new data into your existing array like below:

```
$scope.updateProfile = function(){
$scope.addresses.push($scope.form)
$scope.form = {};
$scope.i = 0;
}
```

add `$scope.form = {}` to your controller to collect the new row, and change your model on the new row to "form." + the column name like below:

```
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='form.site_name ' ></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='form.street_address ' ></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='form.city '></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='form.state ' ></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='form.country ' ></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='form.zip_code ' td>
                                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='form.phone_number '></td>
```

Mind you, you will have to do much more to actually permanently add it to your database.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hbyPkkFIheeNyqnd7aBm?p=preview)

Comment: not working, form Object is null when i check, console.log($scope.form)

Comment: did you define $scope.form = {}; at the top of your controller?  You have to define it before you assign anything to it.  Look at the code in the Plunker.  $scope.form is defined before the page renders.

Comment: check last image of my array

Comment: its not save in array check last image

Comment: when i enter ng-model=' Profile.addresses[2].site_name like this working fine but how to get array index ?

Comment: Just pushing data into the array is not going to save your new row to your database.  It will push it into the array only (which is what you said you wanted when I asked).   That array is being held in $scope variable.  Once you refresh your page it will not show.   If you need it to show after refresh, you will have to save to your database.  What database are you using?